# What is the reason and solution behind this horizontal scroll issue with Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

So I have a container that's supposed to scroll horizontally just like a carousel. It's working just as expected with `<img /` element as the children but not when they're wrapped with `<a></a>`. What is the reason behind this, and what is the solution?

I created a minimal example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JHE3AJ5LUA).

The same example is working as intended though in plain CSS just like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mb0czp6o/8/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is caused by `<img>` elements having `max-width: 100` applied to them with Tailwind. This means that their `min-content` width is effectively `0`, since `max-width: 100%` is resolved relative to their parent `<a>` element. This means that the implicit `flex-shrink: 1` can shrink the `<a>` element.

A solution could be to apply `flex-shrink: 0` to the `<a>` elements to prevent the shrinking:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="flex overflow-x-scroll">
  <a href="#" class="shrink-0">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="shrink-0">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="shrink-0">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="shrink-0">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />  
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="shrink-0">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400" />  
  </a>
</div>
```